# IndexError: index 164 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 164

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I try to drop columns and rows, and reset columns and rows after it. But on the third file, I get error:

> IndexError: index 164 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 164

Files in my folder are `167*164` and, after dropping, are becoming `95*95`.

```
path = r'/home/RESULTS'
allFiles = sorted((glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")))
for file_ in allFiles:
    data = pd.read_csv(file_, header=None)
    data = data.astype(str)
    data = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '.'))
    data = data.astype(float)
    data = data.fillna(value=1)
    data.drop(data.columns[cols_to_drop],axis=1,inplace=True)
    data.drop(data.index[rows_to_drop], inplace=True)
    data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
    data = data.T.reset_index(drop=True).T
    print(file_)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can simplify your solution:

```
path =r'/home/RESULTS' 
allFiles = sorted((glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")))
for file_ in allFiles:
    #decimal for convert float , to .
    data = pd.read_csv(file_, header=None, decimal=',')
    data = data.fillna(value=1)
    #not necessary select columns and index, also ignore drop non exist values
    data.drop(cols_to_drop,axis=1,inplace=True, errors='ignore')
    data.drop(rows_to_drop, inplace=True, errors='ignore')
    data=data.reset_index(drop=True)
    #assign to columns range - reset columns names
    data.columns = range(len(data.columns))
    print(data)
```

Comment: Problem is in data. `3.` file contains only `164 rows`, so not possible drop not exist `165` row (index count from `0`, so first row is `0` and index of `165` row is `164`)

Comment: Another error? It means there are not `164 165 166` values in `index` or `columns`. But solution is `data.drop(rows_to_drop, inplace=True, errors='ignore')` and `data.drop(cols_to_drop,axis=1,inplace=True, errors='ignore')` for ignore droping not existed values.

Comment: but why only from the third file? I believe problem is in columns, because     data.drop(rows_to_drop,axis=1,inplace=True)
data.drop(rows_to_drop, inplace=True) works perfectly

Comment: there are these indexes. and it works on first two files, but on the third is this error

Comment: I understand. check 3. file, there is less columns as you think, so raise error. Also is possible check columns names before droping by `print (data.columns.tolist())`